# Does a promise return the same reference when it is awaited repeatedly

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

Say I have a promise that resolves to an object type. If I keep calling `await` on it, am I guaranteed to get the same reference?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will get the same object back.